# Tango ADF vs Tango3DR ADF

Tags: c++, google-project-tango

**Question**

How compatible are the ADF concepts defined in `tango_client_api.h` and `tango_3d_reconstruction_api.h`? Are they meant to be the same thing, and could in principle be used interchangeably? In that case, how binary compatible are the Tango ADF API and the Tango3DR ADF API? Or are these never meant to be compatibe, they just happen to be named similarly?

**Background**

`tango_client_api.h` lets us save and export ADFs using `TangoService_saveAreaDescription(TangoUUID* uuid)` and `TangoService_exportAreaDescription(const TangoUUID uuid, const char* dst_file_dir);`

Also, `tango_3d_reconstruction_api.h` can generate `Tango3DR_AreaDescription` handles from datasets, and these can be exported to and loaded from files similarly. The `Tango3DR_AreaDescription` handle is further used to create a trajectory from the dataset.

If the two ADF concepts where compatible in some way or another, that would enable features like

- Relating dataset trajectories to coordinate system of previously saved Tango ADFs
- Exporting a Tango3DR ADF, and localizing against this using Tango ADF API.

I briefly tried tried importing a Tango ADF as a Tango 3DR ADF, which did not work particularly well.